# Neo4j gem - Querying multiple parameters in one property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'm not even sure if this title is the best description.

I'm building some basic filtering capabilities via a form for my events. Events have a category from a select drop down.

Now when you want to filter, you can select via checkboxes the categories you want to display.

I'm a bit stumped how to do that. Is it possible to do it all in one query? Or do you separate it into 1 for each category?

My old query was this `current_user.friends.events(:event, :rel).where("rel.admin = {admin_p} AND event.detail = {detail_p}").params(admin_p: true, detail_p: true).pluck(:event)`

In this case, I would need something like `event.category = category1, category2, cateogry3` . Obviously this isn't how it's written. Ways to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how the ruby library works but the format is possibly `AND event.category IN ['cat1','cat2','cat3']` (obviously parameterised)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cypher, `IN` lets you match results within an array.

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r1:INVITED_TO]->(e:Event) WHERE e.uuid IN [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] RETURN e
```

That would match events with any of the uuid properties in that array. In the Ruby gem, this is handled automatically for you in QueryProxy if you use an array in a where method.

```
current_user.events.where(category: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

In your form, ensure that each checkbox's value corresponds with its ID. Put those IDs into an array and search as demonstrated above.

Comment: For people reading, see also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178188/neo4j-gem-querying-from-an-array-object